# How To See The View History Of Google Docs, Sheets & Slides

Tags: google-docs

Looking for a way to access the total number of page views for my Google Docs. In [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739) from Google there is mention of viewing history, and says in step 2:

> At the top, click Tools and then Activity dashboard privacy.

However when click Tools, there is no 'Activity' option:

[image]

I was thinking perhaps this was not showing due to my settings having document history turned off:
[image]

however, even after enabling this feature, and then reloading the document, I still don't see Activity dashboard privacy option at all.

Has this feature been deprecated or is there some setting that will allow me to use this feature?

Running web view of Google Docs on Chrome Version 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) - Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Are you using free Google Workspace or a paid "Work or school" account? I believe this ***Activity dashboard*** is only available for work or school accounts.

Comment: Also, where do you disable that *Show your view history* if you don't have the Tools > Activity dashboard privacy?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am using the free version. To enable the 'Show history' we have to navigate to G-Drive settings (cog top right corner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do that.

The ***Activity dashboard*** mentioned is a feature only available for work or school Google Workspace accounts, and not personal free Google accounts.

The *Activity Dashboard* setting you enabled refers to the Google Drive Activity tab (select the file in Drive and go to the **Activity** tab on the right-side pane.) But this doesn't include granular details like amount of page views etc.

The only possible idea that might work would be to put the link under a link shortener service that gives you analytics, and share the shortened URL instead of the Google URL.

Comment: Thank you. Just the clarification I was hoping for.